# How to conditionally render a functional component depending on origin page?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

This is easy to do in regular JS as an update to the DOM with a parameter, but I have no idea how to do this in React.

Here's the workflow:

- User accesses Table A from page 1
- Table A is populated with ice cream cone data
- Each ice cream cone in the table has a link
- When that link is clicked, it takes you to a new page with a different table (Table B)

Here's the challenge:

- Table B is a functional component filled with ice cream cone data and a mix menu
- I have a new tab called "special tab" on page 2
- Special tab takes you to Table A
- Each ice cream cone in the table still has a link
- **HOWEVER** when the link is clicked, it should take you to Table B **without the mix menu**

Normally in JavaScript you would do something like this:

```
renderTableB( isAccessedFromSpecialTab) {

  if(isAccessedFromSpecialTab){
   //render without mix menu
  } else {
   //render with mix menu
  }
}
```

Since it's React, it seems like the way you pass a variable into a functional component is through props. However, props just seem to be static and don't do anything conditional:

```
function Avatar(props) {
  return (
    <img className="Avatar"
      src={props.user.avatarUrl}
      alt={props.user.name}
    />
  );
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Should it be done with state? I've tried:

1. Duplicating the entire functional component and making clicking the link from special tab take you the new component. However, that solution sucks because it's a ton of code duplication
2. Looked at the React Docs on State, but examples of State assume a component renders differently depending on user input rather than what page it was accessed from.
3. Looked at React Docs on props, but all examples don't have any conditional renders based on props.
4. Looked at stack overflow on conditional renders of props / state, but none work based on the origin page.

I typically find Stack Overflow not helpful, but does anyone have any ideas?

I don't need you to spoonfeed me or solve the problem for me, I just need an example of someone doing something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what would you like to render conditionally, but here are two examples. In the first one we give the src based on props and in the second example we return the avatar conditionally, if user is logged in.

```
function Avatar(props) {
  const src = props.conditionA ? props.user.avatarUrl : placeholder
  const alt = props.conditionA ? props.user.name : ""
  return (
    <img className="Avatar"
      src={src}
      alt={alt}
    />
  );
}
```

```
function Avatar(props) {

  if(!props.loggedIn) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <img className="Avatar"
      src={props.user.avatarUrl}
      alt={props.user.name}
    />
  );
}
```